# H2O GBM and Caret GBM

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting, h2o

Hi I have doubt regarding the interaction. depth parameter in caret. I found a useful link here[about interaction.depth in caret](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/what-does-interaction-depth-mean-in-gbm)

Now I am trying to find the similar parameter in H2O-GBM . Can anyone tell in H2O what is equivalent to interaction.depth that is used in caret-gbm?

Comment: isn't max_depth ? http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/max_depth.html

Answer (score 1):

From the [gbm package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf):

interaction.depth: "Integer specifying the maximum depth of each tree (i.e., the highest level of variable interactions allowed). A value of 1 implies an additive model, a value of 2 implies a model with up to 2-way interactions, etc. Default is 1."

And for more details there is this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/what-does-interaction-depth-mean-in-gbm) on what exactly interaction.depth is, which basically says "Package GBM uses 
 interaction.depth parameter as a number of splits it has to perform on a tree (starting from a single node)".

But note that for every split you make the tree increases its depth. So while interaction.depth in GBM and max_depth in H2O may not be exactly the same thing the numbers map pretty well (i.e. interaction.depth=1 will grow a tree as deep as max_depth=1 in H2O-3), and `max_depth` is the closest option you have to `interaction.depth`

Here are a few images to illustrate what max_depth looks like in H2O-3, but as the linked question suggests, you should use `pretty.gbm.tree function` to explore exactly what interaction.depth does since the R GBM does not build trees the same way H2O-3 does (for example R GBM builds an additional terminal node for missing values which H2O-3 does not do).

max_depth = 1

[image]

max_depth = 2
[image]

max_depth = 3

[image]

Comment: Please check the below link                                                                                    [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/what-does-interaction-depth-mean-in-gbm)                                                                                                       So according to this what I understood is that max_depth is not equal to interaction.depth. Can you please clarify this confusion?

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation for the caret gbm package and point to where they define interaction depth? If the link I have above is incorrect, I'm happy to update the answer. thanks!

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf

Comment: @Kitooos updated the answer, basically max_depth is your closest option to interaction.depth

Comment: Thank you very much Lauren ! I got a clear idea now :)